# Remember me feature in code in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-variables, codeigniter-2

I am trying to have a remember me feature in CodeIgniter. My issue is that after 2 hours or so, my sessions are expiring.

I have tried using:

```
$remember = $this->input->post('remember_me');
if($remember) {
    $this->session->sess_expiration = '1209600';
}
```

And I am suspecting its because of:

```
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
```

in `config.php`. Maybe it's overriding the maximum session time. Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter extend user's session expiration time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603138/codeigniter-extend-users-session-expiration-time)

Comment: @Dan doesn't seem to answer my question

Comment: @Dan Can you open the question in the meantime?

Comment: This one I mean should answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005808/set-session-expiration-time-manually-codeigniter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try like this...

```
$remember = $this->input->post('remember_me');
if($remember) {
    $this->session->sess_expiration = '1209600';
     $this->config->set_item('sess_expiration', 1209600);
}
```

If you would like to dynamically set a config item or change an existing one, you can do so using:

```
$this->config->set_item('item_name', 'item_value');
```

See more here...https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html